# How to update mongodb document and retrieve previous state atomically?

Tags: mongodb

In Mongodb, is it possible to update a document and retrieve it's previous state in an atomic operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). It has a `new` parameter which returns the original document if set to `false` (it's the default).

> Optional. When true, returns the modified document rather than the original. The findAndModify() method ignores the new option for remove operations. The default is false.

Example:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { name: "Andy" },
    sort: { rating: 1 },
    update: { $inc: { score: 1 } },
    new: false
})
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. Although, it was haaard to google this answer. Cheers